# PHP iterate multidimensional array - query web service every x seconds

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have an array with user information and a web service on a site I can query for the status of a user (online/offline). What I would like to do is query the site every x seconds for the status of each user.

There are about 10 users and belwois an example of the array. I can change the array is needed. Only thing I need to enter manually is the username and full name. The "status" I can call from the server.

```
$users = array
(  
  "username"=>array("Fullname","Status"),  
  "johndoe"=>array("John Doe","Online"),
  "janedoe"=>array("Jane Doe","Offline")
);
```

This is an example of the url I can use to query the site (the query returns only the users status (Online or Offline):
http://thesite.com:80/webservice/user/**username**/

This is the code I can use to get a specific user status:

```
$url = 'http://thesite.com:80/webservice/user/johndoe/';
$get = fopen($url, "r");
if ($get) {
    while (!feof($get)) {
        $state = fgets($get, 4096);
    }
    fclose($get);
}

echo "User johndoe is: ".$status;
// Output: User johndoe is: Online
```

**Now I only need help with iterating through the users and site every x seconds and update the array with each user status in the last array field for the user.**

*Please note that below I use php and fopen as this is a cross-domain get function and I could not get ajax/jquery to work. I do not have the option to modify the webservice server.*

Thanks :)

Comment: How are you using the output of the script - is it a CLI or a CGI script?

Comment: Hi, This is intended to be used on a dashboard and i´m only going to display the full name of users that are online.

Comment: And you want to update the dashboard every x seconds, right? Use then javascript to make a partial refresh every x seconds.

Comment: Thanks Al_, i´ll take a look into a JavaScript solution this evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your $users array don't changes, you can do this:

```
foreach($users as $username=>$userdata) {
    $url = 'http://thesite.com:80/webservice/user/'.$username.'/';
    $get = fopen($url, "r");
    if ($get) {
        while (!feof($get)) {
            $state = fgets($get, 4096);
        }
        fclose($get);
    }
    $users[$username][1] = $state;
}
```

If you can change your $users array to be associative like this:

```
$users = array(  
    "username"=>array("fullname"=>"Fullname","status"=>"Status"),  
    "johndoe"=>array("fullname"=>"John Doe","status"=>"Online"),
    "janedoe"=>array("fullname"=>"Jane Doe","status"=>"Offline")
);
```

That would let you use more key/values and a bit safer.

Comment: This is actually perfect. Any chance of helping me echo out all users with the "Online" status? I would like to display the fullname of users that are online.

Comment: I know at 3 ways to do that:
1. echo it inside the foreach (in the snippet I sent before)
2. set a new variable only with online users
3. run a second foreach loop with $users data and use a if condition to echo only the online users.

Do you need the code? Or this is good enough?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a cronjob script that runs every x seconds. That script should be an asynchronous request to this PHP function.

```
public function updateUsers(){
$users = $_SESSION['users'];
foreach($users as $username=>$data) {
    $url = 'http://thesite.com:80/webservice/user/'.$username.'/';
    $get = fopen($url, "r");
    if ($get) {
        while (!feof($get)) {
            $status = fgets($get, 4096);
        }
        fclose($get);
    }
    $users[$username][] = $status;
}
 $_SESSION['users'] = $users;
}
```

A guide for posting asynchronous requests . http://petewarden.typepad.com/searchbrowser/2008/06/how-to-post-an.html

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I´ll take a better look at this later this evening :)